# Компонент не получает новое значение переменной из сервиса

Tags: angular2

Главный компонент в методе `ngOnInit` получает из сервиса значение true. Есть метод, который меняет в сервисе переменную `someValue` на `false`. Но в компонент новое значение не передается. Почему?

```
ngOnInit() {      
    this.isValid = this.validService.getValid();
 }
```

Код сервиса

```
public someValue = true;
getValid(): boolean {
    return this.someValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngOnInit()` вызывается один раз для инициализации компонента. Используйте также`ngDoCheck()` или `ngOnChanges()` для отслеживания изменений.

Comment: `ngDoCheck()` вызывается всегда если есть изменения вне компонента? Т.е. любое изменение в приложении(например, в сервисе) запустит `ngDoCheck()` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869406/angular2-detect-change-in-service тут это подробно расписано